# How to link to "Eye of Gnome" library?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

Here is the command I use:

```
gcc -w -g -export-dynamic -o "%e"  prog.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 `  `pkg-config --cflags --libs eog`
```

My program compiles but I get errors from the linker:

> undefined reference to `eog_image_new'

Here is the output of pkg-config --cflags --libs eog

```
pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/eog-3.0  -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Comment: What does this command `pkg-config --cflags --libs eog` output?

Comment: Added it to the question.